# How to cancel the toast in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    public static final String TAG = "volumeMaster";
    Context cx;
    String evt;
    public FileUtils fileUtils = new FileUtils();
    Toast toast = null;


    public PrijectorLauncher pm = null;@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {


        evt = "getEventType " + event.getEventType() + "\n getWindowId " + event.getWindowId() + "\n getPackageName " + event.getPackageName() + "\n getBeforeText " + event.getBeforeText() + "\n getEventTime " + event.getEventTime() + "\n toString " + event.toString();

        Log.d(TAG, evt);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);
        View toastlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, (ViewGroup) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
        WebView webview = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("iPad");
        webview.getSettings().setPluginsPath("/data/data/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib");
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webview.refreshDrawableState();
        webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/" + cx.getPackageName() + "/cache/");
        webview.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + cx.getPackageName() + "/databases/");
        webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);

        webview.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        webview.setInitialScale(100);

        webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "PRIVYTV");
        webview.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/prijector/pages/accessibility.html");


        toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());


        if (event.getPackageName().equals("com.privytv.prijectorlauncher")) {
            Log.v(TAG, "*****Hiding onAccessibilityEvent");
            // Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            return;
        } else {
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(60000);
            //toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(toastlayout);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            Log.v(TAG, "***** onAccessibilityEvent");
            toast.show();
        }

    }



    public FileUtils getFileUtils() {

        return fileUtils;

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {@Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
        HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

            Log.d("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "WEBVIEW onReceivedHttpAuthRequest : " + host + " " + realm);
            //   handler.proceed("me@test.com", "mypassword");
            handler.proceed("prijector", "android");

        }
    }

    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

        public String getfilelist(String channel) {
            return "BABABABABABABA " + channel;
        }

        public void playSound(String path) {}

        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Log.i(TAG, "DATA FROM JAVASCRIPT SHOTOAST" + toast);
        }

        public void log(String a) {
            Log.i(TAG, "JAVASCRIPT" + a);
        }

        public void loaded(String a) {
            Log.i(TAG, "JAVASCRIPT: WEBVIEW LOADED" + a);
        }

        public void finished(String a) {}
    }

    WebChromeClient chrome = new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        }

        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
        HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

            Log.d("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "WEBVIEW onReceivedHttpAuthRequest : " + host + " " + realm);
            handler.proceed("prijector", "android");

        }

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {}

        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            Log.d(TAG, "WEBVIEW" + consoleMessage.lineNumber() + ":  " + consoleMessage.message());
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "WEBVIEW" + message);
            return true;
        };

    };

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.v(TAG, "***** onInterrupt");
    }



    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {
        Log.v(TAG, "***** onServiceConnected");

        cx = getApplicationContext();
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED;

        info.notificationTimeout = 1000;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
        setServiceInfo(info);

    }




}
```

I am trying to cancel the toast for some particular package,But its not working

Can anyone suggest me, how to achieve that?

and If We display any toast for some particular time,is it possible to hide in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, most cases call Toast's cancel() method has no effect,you can custom an class to manage your project's toast,like this:

```
public class ToastUtil {

private static Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private static Toast toast = null;

private static Object synObj = new Object();

public static void showMessage(final Context act, final String msg) {
    showMessage(act, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

public static void showMessage(final Context act, final int msg) {
    showMessage(act, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

public static void showMessage(final Context act, final String msg,
        final int len) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (synObj) {
                        if (toast != null) {
                            toast.cancel();
                            toast.setText(msg);
                            toast.setDuration(len);
                        } else {
                            toast = Toast.makeText(act, msg, len);
                        }
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}


public static void showMessage(final Context act, final int msg,
        final int len) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (synObj) {
                        if (toast != null) {
                            toast.cancel();
                            toast.setText(msg);
                            toast.setDuration(len);
                        } else {
                            toast = Toast.makeText(act, msg, len);
                        }
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}}
```

Comment: Pls use a `WeakReference<Boast>` to avoid leaking the context if the activity is exited while toast is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`Toast.makeText` returns a Toast object. Call `cancel()` on this object to cancel it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But When package name changes,its still showing the old toast message